# RAM limit for motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard

The [specifications page of my motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.lv/products/page/mb/ga-8i945gzme-rh/) reads:

> Memory:
>   - 2 x DDRII DIMM slots up to 2GB
>   - Supports 1.8V DDRII DIMM
>   - Supports dual channel DDR II 533 DIMM

I already have a 512MB RAM stick in one of the slots - can I add another 2GB stick in the pending slot? I am confused as the the first line of the above specification reads "up to 2GB".

Is it 2GB per slot or the overall limit is 2GB?

**Update 1**: Further perplexing the case, `dmidecode` returns the following output:

`Memory Controller Information

    Error Detecting Method: 8-bit Parity

    Error Correcting Capabilities: 
        None

    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave

    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave

    **Maximum Memory Module Size: 1024 MB

    Maximum Total Memory Size: 4096 MB**

    Supported Speeds:
        Other

    Supported Memory Types:
        Other

    Memory Module Voltage: 5.0 V

    Associated Memory Slots: 4

        0x0006

        0x0007

        0x0008

        0x0009`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [user manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/motherboard_manual_8i945gzme-rh_e.pdf) for your motherboard is a bit clearer:

```
2 DDRII DIMM memory slots (supports up to 2GB memory)
```

I would read this as the board supporting a maximum of 2GB installed, not 2GB per slot.

Comment: Please read the update where `dmidecode` states, It supports upto 4GB.

Comment: I'd think the user manual is more reliable and stick to the overall limit of 2GB.

Comment: Read also from your output where `dmidecode` states:  `**Maximum Memory Module Size: 1024 MB` - your board has two slots, not four.  The chipset supports 4GB but only on boards with four slots.

Comment: Actually, the `dmidecode` output seems to get other particulars wrong, for example:  `Memory Module Voltage: 5.0 V` and `Associated Memory Slots: 4` - I'd definitely trust the user manual over that output.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00550SL0G) and [this](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2304#sp) link, it seems it supports only up to 2GB in total.